# Unable to add user details on Firebase RealTime Database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am currently trying to add user details who have registered in my app using Firebase Phone authentication to Firebase Real time database. I am successfully able to verify a user, but I am not able to send to Details Activity class where I need the user to enter his details, instead I jump to MainActivity Directly.
I do get Toast "Phone Verified" whenever I add a new user.

**Register.java**

```java
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {
    FirebaseAuth auth;
    String phoneNumber;
    String otpCode;
    String verificationId;
    EditText phone, optEnter;
    Button next;
    CountryCodePicker countryCodePicker;
    PhoneAuthCredential credential;
    Boolean verificationOnProgress = false;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    TextView state, resend;
    PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token;
    //FirebaseFirestore fStore;
    DatabaseReference reference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        phone = findViewById(R.id.phone);
        optEnter = findViewById(R.id.codeEnter);
        countryCodePicker = findViewById(R.id.ccp);
        next = findViewById(R.id.nextBtn);
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        state = findViewById(R.id.state);
        resend = findViewById(R.id.resendOtpBtn);

        resend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // todo:: resend OTP
            }
        });


        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (!phone.getText().toString().isEmpty() && phone.getText().toString().length() == 10) {
                    if (!verificationOnProgress) {
                        next.setEnabled(false);
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        state.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        String phoneNum = "+" + countryCodePicker.getSelectedCountryCode() + phone.getText().toString();
                        Log.d("phone", "Phone No.: " + phoneNum);
                        requestPhoneAuth(phoneNum);
                    } else {
                        next.setEnabled(false);
                        optEnter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        state.setText("Logging in");
                        state.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        otpCode = optEnter.getText().toString();
                        if (otpCode.isEmpty()) {
                            optEnter.setError("Required");
                            return;
                        }

                        credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, otpCode);
                        verifyAuth(credential);
                    }

                } else {
                    phone.setError("Valid Phone Required");
                }
            }
        });


    }

    private void requestPhoneAuth(String phoneNumber) {
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, 60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, this,
                new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCodeAutoRetrievalTimeOut(String s) {
                        super.onCodeAutoRetrievalTimeOut(s);
                        Toast.makeText(Register.this, "OTP Timeout, Please Re-generate the OTP Again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        resend.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                        super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
                        verificationId = s;
                        token = forceResendingToken;
                        verificationOnProgress = true;
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        state.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        next.setText("Verify");
                        next.setEnabled(true);
                        optEnter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {


                        verifyAuth(phoneAuthCredential);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(Register.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
    }

    private void verifyAuth(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        auth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Phone Verified", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    checkUserProfile();
                } else {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    state.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Can not Verify phone and Create Account.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            state.setText("Logging IN");
            state.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            checkUserProfile();
        }
    }

    private void checkUserProfile() {
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
        assert firebaseUser != null;
        String userid = firebaseUser.getUid();
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userid);
        if (userid != null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Profile doesnt exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this, Details.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

**Details.java**

```java
public class Details extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String TAG = "TAG";
    EditText firstName,lastName,email;
    Button saveBtn;
    FirebaseAuth auth;
    FirebaseFirestore fStore;
    String userID;
    DatabaseReference reference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

        firstName = findViewById(R.id.firstName);
        lastName = findViewById(R.id.lastName);
        email = findViewById(R.id.emailAddress);
        saveBtn = findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String First_Name=  firstName.getText().toString();
                String Last_Name= lastName.getText().toString();
                String EMail= email.getText().toString();
                    if(firstName.getText().toString().isEmpty()||lastName.getText().toString().isEmpty() || email.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(Details.this, "Fill the required Details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                register(First_Name,Last_Name,EMail);   
            }
        });
}

private void register(String first_name, String last_name, String eMail) {

    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
    assert firebaseUser != null;
    String userid = firebaseUser.getUid();
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userid);
    Map<String,Object> hashmap=new HashMap<>();
    hashmap.put("First Name",first_name);
    hashmap.put("Last Name",last_name);
    hashmap.put("Email-Id",eMail);

    reference.setValue(hashmap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                Intent intent=new Intent(Details.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(Details.this,"Registration failed...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with this code? What exactly doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: @AlexMamo@AlexMamo I wasn't able to get user to update his details after registering . My app was skipping the details activity and directly going to main_activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in your Register class in checkUserProfile() function you are checking if userId from firebaseUser.getUid() is not null. At the moment this will always be not null, because you are already asserting that the user must be authenticated at this point.

Judging from your code this is just a mistake on your part. I assume that what you are trying to do is actually see if the details already exist in the FirebaseDatabase. You have a reference to the database which you are not using.

```
private void checkUserProfile() {
            FirebaseUser firebaseUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
            assert firebaseUser != null;
            String userid = firebaseUser.getUid();
            //Unused reference
            reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userid);
            if (userid != null) {
                 Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this, MainActivity.class);
                 startActivity(intent);
}
```

But also my question would be, are you sure you want to use Realtime Database for user details? You are saving details in Details function using FirebaseFirestore. Didn't you want to check if the details already exist in FirebaseFirestore?

**How to fix:**

First, let's create the user data class:

```
public class User {
    public String uid;
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public String email;

    public User {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
    }

    public User(String uid, String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        this.uid = uid;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Now, let's change the code in Details.java class to use User class:

```
private void register(String first_name, String last_name, String eMail) {

    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
    assert firebaseUser != null;
    String userid = firebaseUser.getUid();
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userid);
    User user = new User(userid, firstName, lastName, eMail)

    reference.setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                Intent intent=new Intent(Details.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(Details.this,"Registration failed...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
  }
```

Let's check if the registration details exist in the database in checkUserProfile() method:

```
private void checkUserProfile() {
                FirebaseUser firebaseUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
                assert firebaseUser != null;
                String userid = firebaseUser.getUid();
                reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userid);
                reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
            }
            else {
            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Profile doesnt exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this, Details.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
}
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Actually i am trying to create messaging app.First i used firestore to for user details and realtime database for messages but the code was getting a bit complicated so i moved to realtime database. Earlier when is was using Firestore for details was able to successfully upload and retrieve details.

Comment: What corrections should me made to make the app run as expected

Comment: After i click on save button no details are saved in realtime database but i move to main activity after clicking on save button in details activity

Comment: Ok, that’s interesting. Because if you move to MainActivity from Details class it means write operation must have been successful.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase will generate a single unique key(UID) on registration of account whether using Email/Phone number. This key remains associated with that account until the account exists in the firebase authentication list.

So, once you register with some number/email at that time UID is created for the same. every time you fetch UID it will return that user UID, and you are also asserting Firebase User is NotNull So, every time you got UID from firebase and app move to the dashboard screen.

If you want to move users to a Detail screen then. You can also add a condition based on firebase User.

```
if(firebaseUser != null){
   // Get UID and Move to Dashboard
}else{
  // Move to Detail Screen
}
```

Comment: Didn't work,same still moving to this Dashboard after adding the above mentioned conditions

Comment: Kindly remove all register phone numbers from Firebase Console.also, you need to update onStart() condition. kindly look at your condition, you are asserting auth.getCurentUser() Is NotNull. it will execute your checkUserProfile() when your FirebaseUser is not null. So, Kindly update your Condition like 1.remove condition from OnStart() methods. 2. add the same condition into checkUserProfile() methods. and navigate screen used on that.